# How to fix error React Native 'UMCore' build error in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, expo

I'm ejecting my Expo app to Expo Kit.
I did so by running `expo eject`, which generated the ios and android files.

When I follow [this](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v30.0.0/expokit/expokit/) guide to run my project, I run `expo start` and expo will run the app on the client.
However, when I try to follow [step 3](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v30.0.0/expokit/expokit/), I run into a problem.

I will go into my ios directory and run `pod install` like so:

```
cd ./ios
pod install
```

After this, I open up Xcode and hit the 'Run' button.

After some seconds, the build fails with 3 errors.
Here's what that looks like:

[image]

As you can see, all of these errors seem to be coming from a development Pod called 'UMCore'.

I've tried deleting all pods and reinstalling them with `pod install`, as well as updating cocoapods and running again, but the issue persists.

This is what my Podfile looks like

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'gearcaster-mobile' do
  pod 'ExpoKit',
    :git => "http://github.com/expo/expo.git",
    :tag => "ios/2.11.2",
    :subspecs => [
      "Core"
    ],
    :inhibit_warnings => true

  # Install unimodules
  require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'
  use_unimodules!(
    modules_paths: ['../node_modules'],
    exclude: [
      'expo-face-detector',
      'expo-payments-stripe',
    ],
  )

  pod 'React',
    :path => "../node_modules/react-native",
    :inhibit_warnings => true,
    :subspecs => [
      "Core",
      "ART",
      "RCTActionSheet",
      "RCTAnimation",
      "RCTCameraRoll",
      "RCTGeolocation",
      "RCTImage",
      "RCTNetwork",
      "RCTText",
      "RCTVibration",
      "RCTWebSocket",
      "DevSupport",
      "CxxBridge"
    ]
  pod 'yoga',
    :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga",
    :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'DoubleConversion',
    :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec",
    :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'Folly',
    :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec",
    :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'glog',
    :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec",
    :inhibit_warnings => true


  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.main_group.tab_width = '2';
    installer.pods_project.main_group.indent_width = '2';

    installer.target_installation_results.pod_target_installation_results
      .each do |pod_name, target_installation_result|

      if pod_name == 'ExpoKit'
        target_installation_result.native_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
          config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] << 'EX_DETACHED=1'

          # Enable Google Maps support
          config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] << 'HAVE_GOOGLE_MAPS=1'
          config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] << 'HAVE_GOOGLE_MAPS_UTILS=1'

        end
      end


      if ['Amplitude-iOS','Analytics','AppAuth','Branch','CocoaLumberjack','FBSDKCoreKit','FBSDKLoginKit','FBSDKShareKit','GPUImage','JKBigInteger2'].include? pod_name
      target_installation_result.native_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
      end
      end

      # Can't specify this in the React podspec because we need to use those podspecs for detached
      # projects which don't reference ExponentCPP.
      if pod_name.start_with?('React')
        target_installation_result.native_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
          config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
        end
      end

      # Build React Native with RCT_DEV enabled and RCT_ENABLE_INSPECTOR and
      # RCT_ENABLE_PACKAGER_CONNECTION disabled
      next unless pod_name == 'React'
      target_installation_result.native_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] << 'RCT_DEV=1'
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] << 'RCT_ENABLE_INSPECTOR=0'
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] << 'ENABLE_PACKAGER_CONNECTION=0'
      end

    end
  end
end
```

### Tool versions:

- Cocoapods 1.7.5
- Expo-CLI 3.0.6
- React-Native: 0.59.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Xcode to version 10 solved this issue